# Variable getting reset after .then chain

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm able to return the likedPosts array if i put my

```
return res.json(likedPosts);
```

inside the forEach loop, but when I put it outside the forEach loop, the response is just an empty array. Don't know how it gets reset...

Here is the full code:

```
exports.getLikedOn = (req, res) => {

    const userHandle = req.user.userHandle;

    db
        .collection('likes')
        .where('userHandle', '==', userHandle)
        .get()
        .then((likes) => {
            let postIds = [];

            likes.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                postIds.push(
                    doc.data().postId
                );
            });
            return postIds;
        })
        .then((postsArray) => {
            let likedPosts = [];
            postsArray.forEach((postId) => {
                console.log(postId); //this returns a the correct post ID
                db
                    .collection('posts')
                    .doc(postId)
                    .get()
                    .then((doc) => {
                        likedPosts.push({
                            postId: posdtId,
                            userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                            userId: doc.data().userId,
                            likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                            shareCount: doc.data().shareCount,
                            commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
                            createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
                        });
                    });
                    // console.log(likedPosts) ---> this prints out the array with 1 post, then 2 ... 
            });
            return res.json(likedPosts); ---> empty array is returned
        })
        .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).json({'Error': `Something went wrong`});
        });
}
```

I need to get the full array, with all the posts in that return res.json(likedPosts)
Any help is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You return value (empty array) before getting result of async operations. Try to use this part instead of second 'then'

```
.then((postsArray) => Promise.all(postsArray.map((postId) => db
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => ({
                postId: postId,
                userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                userId: doc.data().userId,
                likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                shareCount: doc.data().shareCount,
                commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
                createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
            })
        )
)).then((likedPosts)=>{
        res.json(likedPosts)
})
```